# update value based on days in between two birthdays

Tags: sql, sql-update, date

I need to update a variable based on two birthdays

e.g.
I need to update a person's weight measured on his birth date and this value carries on til his next birth date.
say, this person's birth date is 2nd May,
I have his weight measured as 50kg on 2nd May 2013, this value will be updated before his next birthday, in this case, 50kg will be carried til 1st May 2014.

and so on so force,

what's the best way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please mention database name tag, data and desired output so it became more easier to understand.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

try to add 1 year to the saved date: maybe something like this:

```
update unknown_table
   set weight = '60kg'
 where DATE_ADD(saved_birthday,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: where could also be: where DATE_ADD(saved_birthday,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = second_saved_date